# DISTINCT ON combined with ORDER BY returns wrong results

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
results = Tracking.query. \
    filter(Tracking.time >= datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%Y'),).\
    filter(Tracking.time <= datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%Y')).\
    order_by(Tracking.device_id, desc(func.date(Tracking.time))). \
    distinct(Tracking.device_id, func.date(Tracking.time))
```

I have query like above, but resulting the only true result in the early date like this

```
[
    {
        "device_id": 1,
        "device_serial_number": "213123",
        "id": 31419,
        "latitude": "-6.1486514",
        "longitude": "106.894557",
        "time": "Mon, 19 Mar 2018 14:35:20 GMT",
        "video_id": 1,
        "video_name": "dubstep",
        "video_path": "http://localhost:5000/public/files/DubstepBirdOriginal5SecVideo.mp4"
    },
    {
        "device_id": 1,
        "device_serial_number": "213123",
        "id": 13000,
        "latitude": "-6.1509214",
        "longitude": "106.89634459999999",
        "time": "Sat, 17 Mar 2018 00:00:05 GMT",
        "video_id": 1,
        "video_name": "dubstep",
        "video_path": "http://localhost:5000/public/files/DubstepBirdOriginal5SecVideo.mp4"
    },
    {
        "device_id": 1,
        "device_serial_number": "213123",
        "id": 12988,
        "latitude": "-6.151098",
        "longitude": "106.89603483333333",
        "time": "Fri, 16 Mar 2018 23:59:43 GMT",
        "video_id": 1,
        "video_name": "dubstep",
        "video_path": "http://localhost:5000/public/files/DubstepBirdOriginal5SecVideo.mp4"
    }
]
```

16 Mar has the correct result, but others do not, as you can see in the image below: 17 and 19 of March have later data that must be shown.

[image]

If my query is wrong, how can I fix this query?
I try with order by and group by and it same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're truncating the timestamp `Tracking.time` to a date when ordering, so rows with the same device id and date part will be in *unspecified order* relative to each other. DISTINCT ON will then pick what ever row happens to be first.

You'll have to add the time to your ordering one way or another. A quick and dirty solution is to just add the timestamp as 3rd sorting expression:

```
results = Tracking.query. \
    filter(Tracking.time >= datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%Y')).\
    filter(Tracking.time <= datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%Y')).\
    order_by(Tracking.device_id,
             func.date(Tracking.time).desc(),
             Tracking.time.desc()).\
    distinct(Tracking.device_id, func.date(Tracking.time))
```

Alternatively you could cast the timestamp to a time:

```
from sqlalchemy import Time

results = Tracking.query. \
    ...
    order_by(Tracking.device_id,
             func.date(Tracking.time).desc(),
             Tracking.time.cast(Time).desc()).\
```

Comment: I test it and it show error like this FROM tracking 
WHERE tracking.time >= %(time_1)s AND tracking.time <= %(time_2)s ORDER BY tracking.device_id, tracking.time DESC
2018-03-19 15:34:21,356 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'time_2': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 20, 0, 0), 'time_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 16, 0, 0)}
2018-03-19 15:34:21,357 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
why this happen? thank you

Comment: Doesn't look like an error to me. Just normal logging.

Comment: I use try except and it return exception, after I turn off try and exception it show sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (tracking.device_id, date(tracking.time))...

Comment: my code is results = Tracking.query. \
                    filter(Tracking.time >= datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%Y')). \
                    filter(Tracking.time <= datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%Y')). \
                    order_by(Tracking.device_id, Tracking.time.desc()). \
                    distinct(Tracking.device_id, func.date(Tracking.time))

Comment: Ah true, my bad, just a second.

Comment: Thank you, It totally works for adding 3rd sorting expression Tracking.time.cast(Time).desc()